# Removing/Adding Querystring in Window.Location.Href using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery and stuck with one issue and need your help and guidance.

I want to do below three points in my current `window.location.href`:

1. I want to add `?mode=ssl`, if we don't have any querystring in my `window.location.href`
2. I want to append `&mode=ssl`, if there is any querystring in my `window.location.href`
3. I want to remove `logout` querystring from `window.location.href`, if present,
   and then add `mode=ssl` to `window.location`.

Comment: Isn't the query string part of the request? In order to "remove" it you need to redirect in the response, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use something along the lines of the [query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) plugin for jQuery. Makes is drop dead simple to manipulate and retrieve url query values. So, using query to fulfill your requirements:

```
// no need to check for a query string and use `?` or `&`, query does that for us
$.query.set("mode", "ssl");
if ($.query.get("logout")) {
  $.query.set("logout", false);
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest what you are trying to say "no need to check for a query string and use `?` or `&`, query does that for us"

Comment: Any Idea how to use $.query.remove?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Query String Object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, is there any other way as I don't want to add new .js file in my Master page, can't we write the code on same page, please suggest!